# Calc UICollectionViewCell height while downloading image from internet

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I want to create a water fall layout using CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout. I noticed in the demo the cell height is fixed and it's in an array. But, Right now, I got a image url and I want to show it on the screen, but the height is not knowing. So, heightForItemAtIndexPath datasource is not working. How to calc the height of some image url before it's downloaded. Or can I downloading and displaying the image in the cellForItemAtIndexPath datasource method while calc the height and set the cell height in the heightForItemAtIndexPath datasource method? How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If the image is downloaded from your own server, then I would recommend to send meta data first showing the image dimensions and use it to calculate the height before downloading the image.

If the image isn't on your server, then the best solution is to add BOOL array indicating whether the corresponding image is downloaded or not, if downloaded, adjust the height, if not, use the default height.

And add a delegate to your cell which calls the below method when the image is loaded:

```
- (void) ImageLoadedAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath {

     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The image is downloading in the cellForItemAtIndexPath. It means, the height is already calculated, only the image is lazy loading.

Comment: will reloadRowsAtIndexPaths change cell height?

Comment: It should, just try it :)